# getting started with vibe.d

Tags: d, vibed

I'm trying to get vibe.d up and running through dub, as documented at http://vibed.org/docs#first-steps. Following that produced a dub.json like:

```
{
 "name": "accounts",
 "description": "A simple vibe.d server application.",
 "copyright": "Copyright © 2014, aaron",
 "authors": ["aaron"],
 "dependencies": {
    "vibe-d": ">=0.7.17"
 },
 "versions": ["VibeDefaultMain"] 
}
```

When I run `dub`, I get linking errors:

```
Linking...
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -levent
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -levent_pthreads
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
--- errorlevel 1
```

I've tried installing libevent with `brew install libevent`, and played a little with adding a `"dflags_dmd"` field to dub.json, but I can't seem to get it to link up properly.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think vibe.d developers are not focused on MacOS X. Anyhow, try to ask question(s) on the major vibe.d support place - their forum. Link: http://forum.rejectedsoftware.com/groups/rejectedsoftware.vibed/ (you may use NNTP client too).

Comment: Although they might not have their primary focus on MaxOS X it should work - at least here it does. Here I installed the libevent using MacPorts and did not have to change dub.json at all. Can you check if there are the lib event binaries? Here I have: /opt/local/lib/libevent_pthreads-2.0.5.dylib and /opt/local/lib/libevent-2.0.5.dylib  - you should have something similar in a common library location

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the forum; I found someone who had posted about the issue there and managed to fix it. Needed libevent-dev package.

Comment: Can you write it as an answer to yourself so the questions shows up as solved on the index plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer on vibe.d forums: http://forum.rejectedsoftware.com/groups/rejectedsoftware.vibed/post/11075

Had to run `sudo apt-get install libevent-dev`.